# How do I printout a list of names from an array through a string?

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having trouble trying to figure out how to printout a list of names from an array to add alongside other pieces of information. For example this is what I have for a character:

```
public Character(String fn, String ln, String w, int exp)
{
    firstName = fn;
    lastName = ln;
    weapon = w;
    expGained = exp;
}//end Character
```

my toString:

```
public String toString()
{
    String charInformation = "";
    charInformation = "Character Information :" + "\n Name: " + getFirstName() + " " + 
    getLastName() +"\n Weapon Equipped: " + getWeaponName() + "\n EXP Gained: " + getExpGained();
    return charInformation; 
}//end toString
```

Newly created character:

```
Character kaito = new Character("Kaito", "Owari", "Crossbow", 43)
```

The output looks like this:

```
Name: Kaito Owari
 Weapon: Crossbow
 EXP Gained: 43
```

What I want to do is to list the names of his comrades one per line like so:

```
 Name: Kaito Owari
 Weapon: Crossbow
 EXP Gained: 43
 Comrades:
 (Namehere)~Just first and last names
 (Namehere)
 (Namehere)
```

I've made my array I just don't know how to get my toString to list them like above. My array:

```
String firstNames[]={"Max","Owain","Ashe"}
String lastNames[]={"Zero","Matoi","Minami"}
```

Help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

First of all, you shouldn't define your own Character class, because this is a core java class as well. The compiler will accept it, but it is confusing to other programmers and error-prone.

Secondly, I don't understand why you have an array of Strings and not of Characters. If you have an array of Characters and want to utilize your toString method, you can do it as easily as this:

```
Character[] characters = (...) // initialize
for (Character character : characters)
    System.out.println(character);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a loop:

```
String comrades = "";
for (int i = 0; i < firstNames.length; i++) {
    comrades = comrades + "\n" + firstNames[i] + " " + lastNames[i];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate through the array using a for loop. For example:

```
for(int i = 0; i<firstnames.length(); i++)
{
    System.out.println(firstnames[i]);'
}
```

This will print out each index of the array.